# How to build c++ project with MsBuild v15?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I installed the folowing assembly with NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio 2017

```
Microsoft.Build;
Microsoft.Build.Framework.
Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core
```

All is in version 15

I want to build a c++ project with Msbuild

```
    public static void Build(string namePerozhe)
    {
        Logger l = new Logger();

        ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
        pc.DefaultToolsVersion = "15.0";
        pc.Loggers.Add(l);
        Dictionary<string, string> GlobalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        GlobalProperty.Add("Configuration", "Release");
        GlobalProperty.Add("Platform", "Win32");
        BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(namePerozhe, GlobalProperty, null, new[] { "Build" }, null);

        BuildParameters buildParameters = new BuildParameters(pc)
        {
            OnlyLogCriticalEvents = false,
            DetailedSummary = true,
            Loggers = new List<Microsoft.Build.Framework.ILogger> { l }.AsEnumerable()
        };

        var result = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(buildParameters, buildRequest);  
    }
```

But i get the below error :

> The "SetEnv" task could not be loaded from the assembly
>       C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\
>       Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll.
>       Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
>       The system cannot find the file specified.
>       Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available,
>       and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

when i build this project in visual studio it will build with no error . but when i want to build it programmatically this error will throw up.

there is another question that don't have any answer that help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do three main steps:

1. Download the version 15+ Microsoft.Build packages from NuGet. The ones that aren't from NuGet are out of date.
2. **Download the Microsoft.Build.Runtime package**. If you don't download that package, your project might still build, but it'll crash at runtime on `LoadProject`.
3. Hooked up bindingRedirects in my app.config. See: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24545/microsoftbuildcpptaskscommon-references-incorrect.html

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and solved it by adding bindingRedirect to app.config for every msbuild assembly.

Just look at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe.config` and copy necessary blocks to your app.config.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have below blocks in your C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\msbuild.exe.config

```
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral"/>
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.9.9.9" newVersion="15.0.0.0"/>
        </dependentAssembly>
```

Or you may use your own msbuild.exe, make sure you point your env PATH to the right one.