# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS2017, MSBuild version 15.0. I have been installing taichi(https://github.com/yuanming-hu/taichi) .I have been facing lots of errors and trying to solve each step by step and now I am stuck with the following error. I have MSbuid 15.0 but it is looking for version 4.0 .

```
Build FAILED.

       "C:\Users\5000\Documents\spgrid_topo_opt-master\taichi-master\build\taichi.sln" (default target) (1) ->
       "C:\Users\5000\Documents\spgrid_topo_opt-master\taichi-master\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
       (SetTelemetryEnvironmentVariables target) ->
         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Cpp.DesignTi
       me.targets(491,5): error MSB4062: The "SetEnv" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Program Files (x86)
       \Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.dll. Could not
        load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f
       7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask>
       declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a p
       ublic class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [C:\Users\5000\Documents\spgrid_topo_opt-master\tai
       chi-master\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

Comment: Now, is it okay?

Comment: Also stop using the old clunker CMake: It's a pile of spaghetti.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the thing is I am directly running a python file to install. It's a library I want to install. I don't think I can change this.

Comment: wow, python to cmake to visual studio? Sheesh.

Comment: Have you searched your entire machine for Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core.dll ? You should use the "everything" application to search your machine. It provides results in realtime: https://www.voidtools.com/

Comment: I have this in location `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64`  and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`.
Is it fine?

Comment: When I run tools like that. I use the command prompts that come with visual studio. They setup an environment that is conducive to building windows applications.

Answer (score 2):

1.Please open Developer Command Prompt for VS2017(come with build tools) and type the build command like: `msbuild ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj`

2.Check if it makes any difference,if same issue persists open vs installer and update the build tools to latest version. Then build the C++ project to check if it helps

I configured the similar environment like yours. And use the [SetEnv task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/setenv-task?view=vs-2017) in .vcxproj file. But all works well when building the project.

So if all above can't work to resolve the issue: There is possibility that **you call msbuild programmatically** in code. If so, maybe you can get some help from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569137/error-msb4062-the-setenv-task-could-not-be-loaded-from-the-assembly):

Try [binding redirection](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/24545/microsoftbuildcpptaskscommon-references-incorrect.html), thanks to **Nicolas**.

Also, you can check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44340837/how-to-build-c-project-with-msbuild-v15).

Any update feel free to contact me:)

Comment: I updated the buildTools. I still get error on command like `msbuild ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj` . Error is :- `Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=15.0.0.0` . This is because earlier I was facing some issue where project was expecting version 15.0.0.0 . I had 15.1.0.0 . I saw a solution on internet by editing a file by changing the later version into former.

Comment: @ShivamKumar Did you make this file edit regarding the version of `Microsoft.Build.Framework` before encountering the error in your original post? What file did you edit?

Comment: @ShivamKumar I think this issue has something to do with the content of your project. Could you share the simple sample by one-drive or github link so that we can check it directly. Note!: We just need to reproduce the issue, so we don't need your personal code, please delete your personal core code before you share it.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT https://github.com/yuanming-hu/taichi/ . this is the github link for library I am trying to install. There is no code of mine yet. It's just an open source library.

Comment: @weir . I remember I changed msbuild.exe.config(inside bin folder) . I changed 15.1.0.0 into 15.0.0.0 . By the way after updating every tools . I am getting different error. The error I have commented first in this thread.

Comment: @ShivamKumar  Try reverting the edit you made to `msbuild.exe.config`.

Comment: @ShivamKumar Try getting a new clean Zero_Check project and check if binding redirection helps.

Answer (score 1):

Edit your PATH environment variable to ensure the first path to a directory containing msbuild.exe is the one included with Visual Studio 2017. This may be one of the following paths, depending on the edition you have and whether you installed it to the default location.

- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\`

Comment: I only have BuildTools folder and Community folders in that location. So I have path variables as:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` and
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin`

Comment: I see. I thought the issue would turn out to be that the script you were running was invoking a pre-VS 2017 copy of MSBuild somewhere on your machine. For giggles you could try reversing the order in which those 2 paths appear in your `PATH` environment variable, but that's really grasping at straws.

Comment: Well. this is also not working. May be you can take a look at the python file if you can. Here is the link: https://github.com/yuanming-hu/taichi/blob/master/install.py . Let me know if there is anything I can do about it.